# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Problem

Tags: python, opencv

I try to run my bikes detection on opencv python. its work properly when I run it but when the program ends it comes to an error. I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody tell me where the problem is?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
import datetime as dt
from pygame import mixer
import time

#=============== Variable Mouse ==================#
drawing = False
point1 = ()
point2 = ()

drawingTwo = False
pointTwo_1 = ()
pointTwo_2 = ()
Mouse_count = False
#================================================#
def mouse_drawing(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global point1, point2, drawing
    global pointTwo_1, pointTwo_2, drawingTwo, Mouse_count

    #----------Mouse 1-------
    if Mouse_count == False:
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if drawing is False:
                drawing = True
                point1 = (x, y)
            #else:
                #drawing = False

        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if drawing is True:
                point2 = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            drawing = False
            Mouse_count = True



#================================================#
lastTime = dt.datetime.now()
currentTime = dt.datetime.now()

#Make Sound
pygame.mixer.init()


#create VideoCapture object and read from video file


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test13.mp4')

cv2.namedWindow("Detecion motor")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Detecion motor", mouse_drawing)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade11.xml')

    #============================== ROI One ============================#
    if point1 and point2:

        #Rectangle marker
        r = cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (100, 50, 200), 5)
        frame_ROI = frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]]

        #------------------Detect car ROI-------------------#
        if drawing is False:
            #convert video into gray scale of each frames
            ROI_grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(frame_ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            #detect cars in the video
            cars_ROI = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI_grayscale, 1.1, 3)
            if len(cars_ROI) > 0:
                if (currentTime - lastTime).seconds > 20:
                    lastTime = dt.datetime.now()
                    sound = mixer.Sound('sirine2.wav')
                    sound.play()

            for (x, y, w, h) in cars_ROI:
                cv2.rectangle(frame_ROI, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                currentTime = dt.datetime.now()
                # cv2.putText(frame_ROI, "Jumlah Motor : " + str(cars_ROI.shape[0]), (10,frame_ROI.shape[0] -25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5,(0,255,0), 1)
            # -------------------------------------------------#

    #============================== ROI Two ============================#

    #==================================================================#
    cv2.imshow("Detecion motor", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And then the error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Skripsi/CarDetection-master/DeteksiMotor.py", line 65, in <module>
    frame_ROI = frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: My guess would be that frame is None

Comment: i dont get it. how do you put it in the code ?

Comment: Either `frame` or `point1` or `point2` is `None`. The first thing you need to do is to check which one it is.

Comment: how do i check it ?

Comment: For example by printing the variables.

Comment: man i am very bad at this, i dont event know how to try it by printing the variables

Comment: It's probably because at the end of the video, there is no ```frame```, so check ```frame``` is ```None``` after ```cap.read()``` and ```break```.

Comment: how do i write it ?

Comment: ```if not frame: break```after ```ret, frame = cap.read()``` would do it

Comment: it comes with an error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Skripsi/CarDetection-master/DeteksiMotor.py", line 58, in <module>
    if not frame: break
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop the program when the video ends in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608906/how-to-stop-the-program-when-the-video-ends-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0):

Refining @mkrieger1's comment, we can see in your code that you are checking that both `point1` and `point2` for casting to Boolean True, so the problem is not there. By default, then this means that `frame` is equal to None. Replace your line:

```
if point1 and point2:
```

with:

```
if frame and point1 and point2:
```

I mean, `frame` is the result of what looks like an input operation, and these can fail in oh so many creative ways.

Comment: it came out with. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Skripsi/CarDetection-master/DeteksiMotor.py", line 61, in <module>
    if frame and point1 and point2:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: So, obviously, `frame` is a type that does not cast directly to bool. You would probably need to use the `any()` method, although, assuming this is a `numpy` array, I am not familiar with exactly how to call it.

Comment: when i break the video when playing with 'q' button on keyboard, its working normal no error comes out. but when i try finish the video its always come with an error like i mentioned at first. why is that happening ?